# Fixed position overlap absolute position?

Tags: html, css

I try to create a modal but I'm stuck in getting the overlay layer done.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/4z3fss9t/

```css
.modal-wrap{
      display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  padding: 0 40px;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.modal-content{
background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.modal-overlay{
      position: fixed;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrap"> 
    <div class="modal-content"> Content goes here </div> 
    <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

I expect the position absolute would come in front with z-index but it just don't, any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, the whole idea behind `z-index` in CSS is something that confuses most web designers.  It's not rocket science, but you will do yourself a favor by understanding the core concepts behind what's actually happening.  Then the odd behaviors that you are fighting with, will seem much less like voodoo.

### Positioned Elements

First of all, non-`positioned` elements are not affected by `z-index`.  Herein lies your first problem, since (as was noted by Abdul in his answer) your modal content does not have a `position` directive in the CSS.

### Understanding CSS' `z-index` directive

Here is a excerpt from this [excellent article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) by [Philip Walton](http://philipwalton.com):

> ## Stacking Order
>
> Z-index seems so simple: elements with a higher z-index are stacked in front of elements with a lower z-index, right? Well, actually, no. This is part of the problem with z-index. It appears so simple, **so most developers don’t take the time to read the rules.**
>
> Every element in an HTML document can be either in front of or behind every other element in the document. This is known as the stacking order. The rules to determine this order are pretty clearly defined in the spec, but as I’ve already stated, they’re not fully understood by most developers.
>
> When the z-index and position properties aren’t involved, the rules are pretty simple: basically, the stacking order is the same as the order of appearance in the HTML. (OK, it’s actually a little more complicated than that, but as long as you’re not using negative margins to overlap inline elements, you probably won’t encounter the edge cases.)
>
> *When you introduce the position property into the mix, any positioned elements (and their children) are displayed in front of any non-positioned elements.* (To say an element is “positioned” means that it has a position value other than static, e.g., relative, absolute, etc.)
>
> Finally, when z-index is involved, things get a little trickier. At first it’s natural to assume elements with higher z-index values are in front of elements with lower z-index values, and any element with a z-index is in front of any element without a z-index, but it’s not that simple. First of all, z-index only works on positioned elements. If you try to set a z-index on an element with no position specified, it will do nothing. Secondly, z-index values can create stacking contexts, and now suddenly what seemed simple just got a lot more complicated.

### Conclusion

Finally, if you really would like to dive deep, there are some really great resources about `z-index` on the [Mozilla Developers Network](http://developer.mozilla.org)

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

Comment: I saw your profile and it says you're full time free lancer. How do you get enough work and is it more money than working for a company?

Comment: "More money than working for a company" is quite relative... :) I make enough to support my family; most people in the industry wouldn't call it much, but I am happy to be doing what I like at a place I love. My work comes through word of mouth, or from local businesses.

Comment: I see, I work from home too but for a company. I guess the only difference is you don't have to meet with a 'boss' just clients

Comment: @rybread, I enjoyed reading more about Z-index. My side drawer has a fixed position yet all inputs on the form has an absolute position tooltip button. setting `z-index: 2` helped my side drawer to override the content. Thanks for sharing the tips!

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfb3c0ac/)

Something that has `position absolute` doesn't 'automatically' go in front of anything even if you assign it a z-index. If you want z-index to come into effect, you need to define a z-index for everything whose 'depth' you want to control.

in your case, on your `.modal-overlay` do the following:

```
.modal-overlay {
  //your code..
  z-index: 1;
}
```

and this way, your `.modal-wrap` only needs a z-index of 2:

```
.modal-wrap {
  //your code..
  z-index: 2;
}
```

After looking at your fiddle, I see that your modal content is not position absolute or fixed, and you don't have a z-index on it, which means it will go under your modal overlay layer.

You need to define a z-index and give it position absolute or fixed so that it will appear on top of your overlay layer

```
.modal-content {
  position: fixed; //or absolute
  z-index: 2;
}
```